# Reverse order bits in a short

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Is there a function in Apple's library that can reverse the order of the bits in a short?

`0000 0011 -> 1100 0000`

Thanks in advance.

Method used:

```
unsigned int  NO_OF_BITS = sizeof(num) * 8;
unsigned int reverse_num = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_BITS; i++)
{
    if((num & (1 << i)))
        reverse_num |= 1 << ((NO_OF_BITS - 1) - i);
}
```

Source: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/726

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "flip the bits". Usually this means changing all 0's to 1's and vice-versa (i.e. 0000 0011 -> 1111 1100) but it doesn't look like that's what you're after

Comment: Im not talking about masking no..

Comment: That's not really what I was talking about either. It looks like maybe you're trying to flip the *order* of the bits? As in, left-to-right?

Comment: @Sean, exactly. Perhaps i should change the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to reverse the bit sequence of the give byte.

There are lots of way to do this efficiently. Have a look at [http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious)

This site contains lots of tricks when working with bits.